# Why is R giving me NA values when there is data in the dataframe?

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe with several columns and rows but to simplify and get the question across, I've created a dummy dataframe with 0 in it but the error is the same. I cannot see the issue as I've done this process before and never got an error.

```
dummy <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=1, nrow=140253))

dummy$Date <- as.Date.POSIXct(seq(ISOdate(1800,1,1),  by = "days", length.out = nrow(dummy)))
dummy$day <- as.numeric(format(dummy$Date, '%d'))
dummy$month <- as.numeric(format(dummy$Date, '%m'))
dummy$year <- as.numeric(format(dummy$Date, '%Y'))

unique.years <- unique(dummy$year)

for(i.year in 1:length(unique.years)){
  
  year.data <- dummy[dummy$year == unique.years[i.year],]
  if(isLeapYear(year.data$year[i.year])==FALSE){
    lpy <- c(0,0,29,2,unique.years[i.year])
    lyear.data <- insertRow(as.matrix(year.data), 60, lpy)
  }else{
    lyear.data <- dummy[dummy$year == unique.years[i.year],]
  }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve but going through the code it gave me error that said:

```
Error in if (isLeapYear(year.data$year[i.year]) == FALSE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Then I realised that this was due to the fact that it was not reading all years of the dataframe, I checked this by only running the first part and printing the following, giving the list with NA from year 2164:

```
for(i.year in 1:length(unique.years)){
  
  year.data <- dummy[dummy$year == unique.years[i.year],]
  print((year.data$year[i.year]))
}
+   print((year.data$year[i.year]))}
[1] 1800
[1] 1801
[1] 1802
[1] 1803
[1] 1804
[1] 1805
[1] 1806
[1] 1807
[1] 1808
[1] 1809
[1] 1810
[1] 1811
[1] 1812
[1] 1813
[1] 1814
[1] 1815
[1] 1816
[1] 1817
[1] 1818
[1] 1819
[1] 1820
[1] 1821
[1] 1822
[1] 1823
[1] 1824
[1] 1825
[1] 1826
[1] 1827
[1] 1828
[1] 1829
[1] 1830
[1] 1831
[1] 1832
[1] 1833
[1] 1834
[1] 1835
[1] 1836
[1] 1837
[1] 1838
[1] 1839
[1] 1840
[1] 1841
[1] 1842
[1] 1843
[1] 1844
[1] 1845
[1] 1846
[1] 1847
[1] 1848
[1] 1849
[1] 1850
[1] 1851
[1] 1852
[1] 1853
[1] 1854
[1] 1855
[1] 1856
[1] 1857
[1] 1858
[1] 1859
[1] 1860
[1] 1861
[1] 1862
[1] 1863
[1] 1864
[1] 1865
[1] 1866
[1] 1867
[1] 1868
[1] 1869
[1] 1870
[1] 1871
[1] 1872
[1] 1873
[1] 1874
[1] 1875
[1] 1876
[1] 1877
[1] 1878
[1] 1879
[1] 1880
[1] 1881
[1] 1882
[1] 1883
[1] 1884
[1] 1885
[1] 1886
[1] 1887
[1] 1888
[1] 1889
[1] 1890
[1] 1891
[1] 1892
[1] 1893
[1] 1894
[1] 1895
[1] 1896
[1] 1897
[1] 1898
[1] 1899
[1] 1900
[1] 1901
[1] 1902
[1] 1903
[1] 1904
[1] 1905
[1] 1906
[1] 1907
[1] 1908
[1] 1909
[1] 1910
[1] 1911
[1] 1912
[1] 1913
[1] 1914
[1] 1915
[1] 1916
[1] 1917
[1] 1918
[1] 1919
[1] 1920
[1] 1921
[1] 1922
[1] 1923
[1] 1924
[1] 1925
[1] 1926
[1] 1927
[1] 1928
[1] 1929
[1] 1930
[1] 1931
[1] 1932
[1] 1933
[1] 1934
[1] 1935
[1] 1936
[1] 1937
[1] 1938
[1] 1939
[1] 1940
[1] 1941
[1] 1942
[1] 1943
[1] 1944
[1] 1945
[1] 1946
[1] 1947
[1] 1948
[1] 1949
[1] 1950
[1] 1951
[1] 1952
[1] 1953
[1] 1954
[1] 1955
[1] 1956
[1] 1957
[1] 1958
[1] 1959
[1] 1960
[1] 1961
[1] 1962
[1] 1963
[1] 1964
[1] 1965
[1] 1966
[1] 1967
[1] 1968
[1] 1969
[1] 1970
[1] 1971
[1] 1972
[1] 1973
[1] 1974
[1] 1975
[1] 1976
[1] 1977
[1] 1978
[1] 1979
[1] 1980
[1] 1981
[1] 1982
[1] 1983
[1] 1984
[1] 1985
[1] 1986
[1] 1987
[1] 1988
[1] 1989
[1] 1990
[1] 1991
[1] 1992
[1] 1993
[1] 1994
[1] 1995
[1] 1996
[1] 1997
[1] 1998
[1] 1999
[1] 2000
[1] 2001
[1] 2002
[1] 2003
[1] 2004
[1] 2005
[1] 2006
[1] 2007
[1] 2008
[1] 2009
[1] 2010
[1] 2011
[1] 2012
[1] 2013
[1] 2014
[1] 2015
[1] 2016
[1] 2017
[1] 2018
[1] 2019
[1] 2020
[1] 2021
[1] 2022
[1] 2023
[1] 2024
[1] 2025
[1] 2026
[1] 2027
[1] 2028
[1] 2029
[1] 2030
[1] 2031
[1] 2032
[1] 2033
[1] 2034
[1] 2035
[1] 2036
[1] 2037
[1] 2038
[1] 2039
[1] 2040
[1] 2041
[1] 2042
[1] 2043
[1] 2044
[1] 2045
[1] 2046
[1] 2047
[1] 2048
[1] 2049
[1] 2050
[1] 2051
[1] 2052
[1] 2053
[1] 2054
[1] 2055
[1] 2056
[1] 2057
[1] 2058
[1] 2059
[1] 2060
[1] 2061
[1] 2062
[1] 2063
[1] 2064
[1] 2065
[1] 2066
[1] 2067
[1] 2068
[1] 2069
[1] 2070
[1] 2071
[1] 2072
[1] 2073
[1] 2074
[1] 2075
[1] 2076
[1] 2077
[1] 2078
[1] 2079
[1] 2080
[1] 2081
[1] 2082
[1] 2083
[1] 2084
[1] 2085
[1] 2086
[1] 2087
[1] 2088
[1] 2089
[1] 2090
[1] 2091
[1] 2092
[1] 2093
[1] 2094
[1] 2095
[1] 2096
[1] 2097
[1] 2098
[1] 2099
[1] 2100
[1] 2101
[1] 2102
[1] 2103
[1] 2104
[1] 2105
[1] 2106
[1] 2107
[1] 2108
[1] 2109
[1] 2110
[1] 2111
[1] 2112
[1] 2113
[1] 2114
[1] 2115
[1] 2116
[1] 2117
[1] 2118
[1] 2119
[1] 2120
[1] 2121
[1] 2122
[1] 2123
[1] 2124
[1] 2125
[1] 2126
[1] 2127
[1] 2128
[1] 2129
[1] 2130
[1] 2131
[1] 2132
[1] 2133
[1] 2134
[1] 2135
[1] 2136
[1] 2137
[1] 2138
[1] 2139
[1] 2140
[1] 2141
[1] 2142
[1] 2143
[1] 2144
[1] 2145
[1] 2146
[1] 2147
[1] 2148
[1] 2149
[1] 2150
[1] 2151
[1] 2152
[1] 2153
[1] 2154
[1] 2155
[1] 2156
[1] 2157
[1] 2158
[1] 2159
[1] 2160
[1] 2161
[1] 2162
[1] 2163
[1] 2164
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is. There are no days missing and I cannot figure out why it stops after 2164.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stops after 2164 because 2165 is the 366th year. This because you are taking the `i.year`th index of `year.data`, but each `year.data` is 365 rows so when you reach `i.year == 366` you are out of bounds and will get `NA` back.

I'm guessing you just want to check if the current year is a leap year? Well, all the rows will have the same `year` value in the `year.data` df so just change your if statement to

```
if (!isLeapYear(unique.years[i.year]))
```

and that should fix it. Also note that `!condition` is preferred over `condition == FALSE`.

Comment: @dpht05 If you changed your if statement to my suggestion and get the same error that's very strange. But anyway, why do you want to do this? The leap days are already in the original dataset. Since this is just a dummy example, will the real data be different in structure?

Comment: Sorry, it does fix it. Thanks very much for your reply!!